# How to give push and pull access to a Collaborator in public repo on GiHub

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub, can you please tell "How to give push and pull access to a Collaborator in public repo on GiHub"

I added a collaborator to my public repo and system automatically displays Push access to repository. I need collaborator to have Pull Access as well.

Comment: Add the console output when you try to pull. As far as i know everyone has pull(read) access on public repos by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Github Help](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/#collaborator-access-on-a-repository-owned-by-a-user-account), assuming that yours is a *user account repository*, a Collaborator can push and pull to that repository.

Therefore, your collaborator has already permission to pull.